# Can't declare another window

Tags: ios, window, appdelegate

I'm trying to declare another window in MyThing.m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
```

But get this error

> Illegal redeclaration of property in class extension
>   "MyThing" (attribute must be 'readwrite', while its primary
>   must be 'readonly')

If I rename window to something else, it is OK. Why is that? Is window meant to be declared once in the AppDelegate.h ?

Comment: You already have a property named `window`. You can't add a 2nd.

Comment: @rmaddy but the window is declared in AppDelegate.h, while here I declare in MyViewController.m, is that not acceptable too ?

Comment: Show both declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure out the problem, it has nothing to do with the window property declared in AppDelegate.h

The problem is MyThing conforms to UIApplicationDelegate, and UIApplicationDelegate protocol declare a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

So we must do either of these

**MyThing.h** (like AppDelegate.h does)

```
@interface MyThing : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

OR

**MyThing.m** (synthesize the window property declared in protocol)

```
@implementation WYNAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

@end
```